# List comprehension - 2 element list

Tags: python, list

Create 2-element lists -

```
["atom", "nuclei", "neuron"] to display as:
```

Counting the number with the list and result to display something like this =

```
[["atom",4], ["nuclei",6], ["neuron", 6], ["physics", 7]]
```

Answer (score 2):

Here:

```
>>> my_list = ["atom", "nuclei", "neuron"]
>>> [[v, len(v)] for v in my_list]
[['atom', 4], ['nuclei', 6], ['neuron', 6]]
```